# Adding a time stamp for data inserted into Google Sheets using Google BigQuery / Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I'm following the code sample [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery#run_query) to insert data from BigQuery into Google Sheets using Google Apps Script.

I was able to get the script to work, but I would like to add an updated timestamp to the data as a new column.

Referring to the sample above, in this specific section:

(Original code)

```
  if (rows) {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create('BiqQuery Results');
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

    // Append the headers.
    var headers = queryResults.schema.fields.map(function(field) {
      return field.name;
    });
    sheet.appendRow(headers);

    // Append the results.
    var data = new Array(rows.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      var cols = rows[i].f;
      data[i] = new Array(cols.length);
      for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
        data[i][j] = cols[j].v;
      }
    }
    sheet.getRange(2, 1, rows.length, headers.length).setValues(data);
```

To give an example of what I am trying to achieve, say if I ran this query:
`select sample_data from data limit 3`

Results:

```
sample_data
1
2
3
```

I would like to add an additional column of data with the current timestamp. I can do this by:
`select sample_number, current_timestamp() as now from data`

```
sample_number   now
1               2021-07-29 06:19:04.291269 UTC
2               2021-07-29 06:19:04.291269 UTC
3               2021-07-29 06:19:04.291269 UTC
```

But I would like to achieve this result using Google Apps Script, so that I don't need to append `current_timestamp() as now` to all SQL queries that would be called using this module.

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
sheet.getRange(2, 1, rows.length, headers.length + 1).setvalues(new Date());
```

However, I think it would be a column length mismatch.

I'm thinking I would need to add a new column to the array, then add `new Date()` as row values, before calling `.setValues()` to write the array to Google Sheets, but not sure how to do it.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

[setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) requires an `Object[][]`.

You should add the 'date column' to your `data` array and then `setValues`

```js
const date = new Date();
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (i === 0) { row.push('now'); }
  else { row.push(date); }
}
sheet.getRange(2, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
```